# Что за операторы '??=' и '!!=' в PHP?

Tags: php, php7, php8

Что за операторы  `??=`  и  `!!=`  в PHP ?

Comment: `a ??= b` => `a = a ?? b`. А `!!=` вообще вызывает синтаксическую ошибку.

Comment: Какая версия PHP?

Comment: !!= такого нет, в доках пусто, да и первый раз слышу о таком

Comment: Любая версия php https://3v4l.org/h8PQI

Comment: @u_mulder, неправильно. `a ?? (a = b)` - вот доказательство: https://3v4l.org/e62A6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lhs ??= rhs` это то же самое, что `lhs ?? (lhs = rhs)` и вот подтверждающий это код:

https://3v4l.org/GKlnG

```
class Smth {
  public function __get($name) {
    echo "Get: $name\n";
    return $name == "abc" ? null : 0;
  }

  public function __set($name, $value) {
    echo "Set: $name to $value\n";
  }
}

$x = new Smth();
$x->abc ??= 7;
$x->cde ??= 8;
```

```
Get: abc
Set: abc to 7
Get: cde
```

Стоит заметить, что в выводе нет строки set cde.

Если бы оператор разворачивался в `lhs = lhs ?? rhs`, то она бы была.

Comment: Мне больше интересно откуда вообще взялось `??=` ибо в доках о нём ни слово, кроме `??`. Напишу issue в репозиторий с вопросом.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev отчего же. В 7.4 есть http://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration74.new-features.php

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator   ..... https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-74  что-то кверти намудрил)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский о, точно, я смотрел на странице операторов и там не было. Видимо просто никто не обновлял общую страницу...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну да))) Зато у меня пример кода есть))